# How do I put Wallet passes on Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, wallet

How do I sync the passes in Wallet on my iPhone with those on my Watch. I've recently added some passes to my phone, but they're not appearing on my watch.

Comment: How are you trying to add them to your Watch?

Comment: @fsb I don't see any way, that's the question. What's there is not in sync with what's on the iPhone.